# Remote network administration, solving 2 device 2 subnet merge

Tags: networking, router, vpn, subnet

**The problem:**

**1.)**  No Physical Access

**2.)**  Very basic on site help

**3.)**  Combining 2 subnets on 2 routers

Now we know i cant go on site to move cords around so here are the current cord configurations. They can be changed by on site employees but that is a last choice kind of thing.

**Modem**-------> **(WAN)Cisco firewall RVS4000** ------>**(Lan)Switch**----->**(WAN)Asus RT-AC66U**

**Who can see who:** Asus can see its and cisco's network, Cisco cannot see anything past the asus Wan port.

**Where do i have admin:** I have DYNDNS to the the Cisco, I have Logmein on pc's in the Cisco subnet. I have Logmein on Pc's in the Asus subnet. I DO NOT have direct admin to the Asus.

I need to make the Asus's subnet the same as the Cisco's, and normally i would just change the settings on them and if it doesn't work id just try again until it does work. That however isn't an option, if i lose connectivity to this due to a bad choice in routing i have to walk an on site user through resetting it so i can log into an on site pc and change it again.

I know changing my default gateway or having the cisco preform all DHCP is either the correct answer or close to the correct answer. I however do not have many opportunities to wing it...

**I do understand this is not a complicated question, but this requires a somewhat complicated solution. The complicated solution process is the reason i posted here, otherwise i wouldn't muddle the board with this kinda stuff.**

Thanks.

Ben

Answer (score 0):

Routers exist to pass traffic between different (sub)networks.  If you have the same subnet on both the LAN and WAN sides of a router, it won't work (at least not properly, if at all).

If I understand correctly, the goal is to get the devices on the LAN side of the Asus into the same subnet as those on the LAN side of the Cisco, then just take the Asus out of the network, and plug the devices that were on the LAN side of the Asus directly into the switch (or depending on wiring conditions/placement, replace the Asus router with a switch, or move the wire from the WAN side and plug it into the LAN side and use the Asus router's LAN-side (only) as a switch).

Those devices can then get DHCP info from wherever the devices on the existing Cisco LAN are.